# Are there graphical Nethack clients that connect to public servers?

Tags: nethack

So, there is the nethack.alt.org server where many users have gone and had their good times, using the text-based interface through a client such as PuTTY (or your favorite terminal client).

Anyway, I don't mind playing Nethack in console mode... However I do rather enjoy the graphical version far more.  Are there any clients available that make use of graphical tilesets, and can connect to a public server?

Comment: The only such thing I'm aware of is the super awesome https://tiles.crawl.develz.org/ HTML5 (canvas + websockets) client for Dungeon Crawl. The problem is this requires a good MVC separation that's lacking in most roguelikes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am hosting a public server which give the possibility to play a graphical nethack with tiles in a javascript frame. I am looking for people in order to try it.
So you are welcome :)
It's almost the same feeling as playing the windows/linux graphical version but with statistics and high-score online. And you have nothing to download.

http://newthack.com

Comment: very cool...one thing i noticed was that my human valkyrie had a duplicate one tile to the right which followed me around...